How do I hide animations while loading a web page in Streamlit?
How do I hide animations while loading a web page in Streamlit?
I'm working on a web app in Streamlit and I am looking hide animations while loading a web page .
st.set_page_config(page_title=“Page Title”, layout=“wide”, page_icon=“395.ico”)
st.markdown(“”"

.reportview-container {
margin-top: -2em;
}
#MainMenu {visibility: hidden;}
.stDeployButton {display:none;}
footer {visibility: hidden;}
#stDecoration {display:none;}

“”", unsafe_allow_html=True)






HowTo hide animations while loading a web page in Streamlit?
